# Setting variable to specified workbook generates out of range error

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I am trying to write some simple code that pulls ranges from one workbook (source) and pastes them into another workbook (consolidate). I want the "source" workbook to be specified as I run the macro from "consolidate" workbook.

The below code works fine while I use "Workbooks.Open(...." but when I remove ".Open" (eg, Workbooks(##filename##)) I get a subscript out of range error.

I am using Excel 2013, but it appears both workbooks are in the same instance (I can see them both in the VBA project list). The filename is correct and includes the extension (again - code as below works perfectly while I ".Open" it, but I want to be able to run the code multiple times and I don't want to have to keep opening the file over and over again).

The code also works with ActiveWorkbook, but requires me to navigate to the "source" workbook first and then running the macro which is also not preferred.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wbk_data as Workbook 'source book
Dim wbk_cons as Workbook 'consolidate book
Dim wbk_data_s as Worksheet 'source sheet
Dim wbk_cons_s as Worksheet 'consolidate sheet

Dim target As String
    target = [wbk_name].Value2 'filename is included as a named cell in the worksheet

Set wbk_data = Workbooks(target) 'this is the line that doesn't work. 
    'Set wbk_data = Workbooks.Open(target) does work in this place
Set wbk_cons = ThisWorkbook
Set wbk_data_s = wbk_data.Worksheets("ExampleSrcSheet")
Set wbk_cons_s = wbk_cons.Worksheets("ExampleConsSheet")
```

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: So open it and don't close it until you're done?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Ideally that's exactly what I'd do - the issue is that whenever I call this Sub it will attempt to re-open the file, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Either you open the workbook (and then close it), or otherwise make sure it's opened so that it's in the `Workbooks` collection. `Workbooks("not loaded")` will always throw an *index out of range* error - that error basically means "the index/key you specified was not found in the array/collection".

Comment: Mathieu - that sounds promising. How should I ensure it is added to the Workbooks collection?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it's already open, and open it if not:

```
Dim target As String
target = [wbk_name].Value2 

'see if it's already open 
On Error Resume Next 'ignore any error on the next line
Set wbk_data = Workbooks(target)
On Error Goto 0      'stop ignoring errors

'if not already open, open it
If wbk_data Is Nothing Then
   Set wbk_data = Workbooks.Open(target)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I actually ended up adding similar code. The result was that it would still throw the error and try to open the workbook again each iteration. Still trying to figure out why it can't be used as a variable while still open...

Comment: Because the text you use to open it doesn't match the name when it's open? Do you have a path in target? Inthe immediate window type  For each wb in workbooks:debug.print wb.name:next wb  and see what it outputs as the name of the workbook

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am not a regular VBA user and I'm not totally sure how do do what you've described. Will what you've written work as code word for word? I don't use the "debug." operator often.